# ARM Cortex-M3 Reference manual mentioning LDR Rx!,[any] as a valid instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, armv7

When reading through the Cortex-M3 reference manual there is a section called [Load/Store timings (3.3.2)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/h/programmers-model/instruction-set-summary/load-store-timings) where they discuss ways to minimize the number of clock cycles a Load/Store instruction takes.

One of the rules is stated as follows:

> LDR Rx!,[any] is not normally pipelined. That is, base update load is generally at least a two-cycle operation (more if stalled). However, if the next instruction does not require to read from a register, the load is reduced to one cycle. Non register writing instructions include CMP, TST, NOP, and non-taken IT controlled instructions.

To my knowledge, only pre-indexed memory instructions use a '!' to indicate base-update loads and only in the following way:
`LDR Rx, [Ry, #n]!` .

`LDR Rx!, [any]` would mean that the destination register is updated in a pre-indexed way, this obviously doesn't make any sense, so I'm wondering if this means something else or is it just a mistake/typo in the manual?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  Most likely, `LDM Rx!, {any}` was meant.

Comment: `LDM` is referred to separately.  I think it means `LDR Rx, [any]` (with update in 'any') and they give pseudo-code as `LDR [any]` later.  The quoted text is just saying that if a registers is not used in a subsequent instruction, you count the LDR as a single cycle.  There are two forms. `LDR  R0, [R1, #42]!` (pre update) and `LDR  R0, [R1], #42` (post update).  Don't take the pseudo notation too seriously.

Comment: I don't think there is an `LDR Rx, [Ry, #n]!`, but the pseudo instruction `LDR Rx, [any]!` might have been better.  They mean both pre and post indexed updates.  The referenced page is definitely not referring to **literal** arm instructions.